# How to change Color of button2 in swift when button1 is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, button, swift3

All I want to do is change the `backgroundColor` of fiveMinButton and tenMinButton when fiveMinButton is clicked. Why doesn't this code work? `@IBAction` will not work either.

```
@IBOutlet weak var fiveMinButton: UIButton!



 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fiveMinButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("action:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    func action(sender: UIButton){

        if sender === fiveMinButton {

            fiveMinButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            tenMinButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightgray

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 problems with your code.

1. The syntax of `selector`is wrong
2. You have added action of your button inside the `viewDidLoad` that will also wrong, so write that method outside the `viewDidLoad` as class method.

For first one change selector like this.

```
fiveMinButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

For second problem just write action out side the `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: `fiveMinButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)` was the correct syntax. Fixed my solution

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: Point 3 is incorrect. The use of `===` is correct since the check is to see if `sender` and `fiveMinButton` are the same reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the action method inside the viewDidload, Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fiveMinButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

}

func action(sender: UIButton){
        if sender == fiveMinButton {
            fiveMinButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            tenMinButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightgray
        }
}
```

Comment: change `===` to `==`.

Comment: app is still crashing. Error Log: `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: are you using swift 3?

Comment: @Mr.UB your selector syntax is still wrong either add `_` as first parameter inside `action`method or change selector with #selector(action(sender:))

Comment: Which swift version?

Answer (score 0):

If button type rounded rect ..Color cannot be applied. So set the button to type custom and good to go

```
self.myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

or you can set the background image or image to the button to gain the color

```
self.myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageNamed("myButtonImage.png"), forState: UIControlStateNormal)
```

or

```
self.myButton.setImage(UIImage.imageNamed("myButtonImage.png"), forState: UIControlStateNormal)
```